# Fallback route for .NET Core 6 application

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an application written on .NET 6. This app has a Web UI (Blazor Server side, render-mode="Server") and a REST API (endpoints described in controllers).
I use the next code to configure app:

```
...
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
app.MapControllers();
...
```

The problem is Blazor doesn't support 404 status code (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45654), so if route not found, my service returns a 200 status code.

For WebUI it's is not a big problem (because I can display some content with description message). But for REST API it's a very big problem. And I need some workarounds.

All of my API routes starts with "/api/..." prefix. So as idea I want to set up some endpoint which should process AFTER all controllers endpoints, but BEFORE blazor. Possibly in that enpoint I can check, if path start with "/api/...", and return 404. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add a middleware to pipeline
like this:

```
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var endpoint = context.GetEndpoint();
    if (context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api") && !endpoint.Metadata.Any(e => e is ApiControllerAttribute))
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
        return;
    }
    await next(context);
});
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
```